# Failing to find nan values but program is detecting them in data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

```
 import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel

    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

    data = pd.read_csv("filtered aggregated data.csv")

    mask = data["Fit"].str.contains("Storefront").astype(bool)
    data = data[~mask]

    data["6 Mo. Growth Count"] = data["6 Mo. Growth 
    Count"].fillna("NaN")

    sixMoData = data[data["6 Mo. Growth Count"] != "NaN"]

    sixMoData["Fit"] = sixMoData["Fit"].astype("category")

    sixMoData = pd.get_dummies(sixMoData, columns= 
     ["Category","Country"])

    sixMoData.dropna(inplace=True)
    sixMoData.reset_index(inplace=True)

   X = sixMoData[sixMoData.columns[3:]]
   y = sixMoData["Fit"]



   for col in X.columns:
        containsNa = any(X[col].isna())
        containsInf = any(X[col].isin([np.inf, -np.inf]))
        if containsNa or containsInf:
            print(col)

        X[col] = X[col].astype(float)


   model = OrderedModel(y, X)
```

When I run this code, I find that there are no columns that contain an nan value based on the checks that I run here. However, when I try to run the model, I get an error stating: "exog contains inf or nans", where exog refers to the X dataframe. What am I doing incorrectly when checking for nans?

Comment: did you check for `inf` in `X`?

Comment: I did, and this was how. **containsInf = any(X[col].isin([np.inf, -np.inf]))**